# A question about the constraints in BRST-Fock theories

Tags: quantum-field-theory, gauge-theory, constrained-dynamics, brst

In *BRST Symmetry in the Classical and Quantum Theories of Gauge Systems*, Henneaux says the Fock representation is not applicable to an odd number of constraints. Then he goes on to say that the Kugo-Ojima quartet requires the constraints to be in pairs. For BRST theories, when are they not in pairs?

Comment: Full reference: M. Henneaux, _BRST Symmetry in the Classical and Quantum Theories of Gauge Systems._ Published in _Quantum Mechanics of Fundamental Systems,_ (Editor C. Teitelboim), 1988, chapter 10, p. 138.

Answer (score 0):

A stupid answer is to take the action
$$L = \frac{(\dot{q}_1-\dot{q}_2)^2}{2} + \frac{(q_1-q_2)^2}{2}.$$
It has only one constraint, $p_1+p_2=0$.

I don't know any more physical example, but I wouldn't be surprised if one exists.

There are at least two less stupid answers.

The first is (3+1)-d Maxwell theory in $A_0 = 0$ gauge, because then the only constraint is Gauss' law $\nabla \cdot E = 0$.
There are corresponsing ghosts that have no dynamics because this only consists of time-independent gauge transformations.
As a result, no one really talks about them.

The second is (0+1)-d Maxwell theory, where the only gauge-invariance is that generated by $\Pi^0$, the momentum conjugate to $A_0$.
This is basically the converse of the previous example, freezing space instead of time.

Comment: How does this answer the question "*For BRST theories, when are they not in pairs?*"?

Comment: Well, you can write a BRST charge $Q = \eta (p_1+p_2)$ and all the machinery of BRST works. Is there a more involved meaning of "BRST theory?"